# What is the meaning of method class in the class definition in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm familiar with function definitions and variable declarations being in class definitions:

```
public class MyClass {
  public int myvar;
  public void doSomething() {

  }
}
```

But what does it "mean" in Ruby when a method is actually called in the class definition? This happens amply in Rails, for instance:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

What exactly does this do (at a lower level than "it adds some methods to the class")? How would I implement such a function (e.g., one that mixes in some additional methods)?

Comment: I suspect, but I'm not certain, that some languages have code that runs at compile time and code that runs at run-time. I think ruby generally runs at run-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During the definition of a class, the receiver is the class object, and so it's really about the same thing as the more familiar *class* ***.*** *method* technique of calling a class method.

```
>> class A
>>   def self.hello
>>     puts 'world'
>>   end
>>   hello
>> end
world
=> nil
>> A.hello
world
=> nil
>> class B < A
>>   hello
>> end
world
=> nil
```

So, to carry the ClassName.new analogy a bit further, you can call any class method this way. Let's use `new` as an example:

```
>> class C
>>   def happy
>>     puts 'new year'
>>   end
>>   new
>> end.happy
new year
=> nil
```

BTW, don't get confused by the fact that this method is defined in the superclass. ***Q:*** What's the difference between your derived class and your superclass instance? Say `ActiveRecord::Base`?  ***A:*** Nothing! There is only the one class instance.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed based on your example that 'world' was not printed twice when you declared `B`. Is it correct to deduce that when extending a class, the method invocations in the class definition do not get applied (I would presume that method calls like `has_many` actually do change the class definition at runtime and therefore effectively get 'inherited' to that extent, though)? Any additional weirdness I should be aware of?

Comment: has_many modifies data stored in the Model class. The data structures modified are defined in ActiveRecord::Base or other modules already mixed in. You should have a look at the source code in A/R, there is much mixin coolness going on in Rails

Comment: Sure, but I don't think the OP was really asking exactly what Rails does, which certainly includes lots of metaprogramming magick. I mean, the OP specifically asked: "how would I implement such a function?". Well, this is the answer to that exact question.

Comment: Indeed it is. I was just suggesting that looking at the Rails codebase is a great way to see how these 'tricks' are used in practice. Not the only way or place to look but a good one.

Comment: btw the OP did specifically ask how to mix in methods to a class

Comment: I was experimenting with your class A, and I was trying to discover whether the methods calls in the class definition were invoked after the class was "defined" in the traditional sense by parsing all the methods definitions in the class definition body. So I moved `hello` above the definition of `self.hello`. It gave me a NameError, so it indeed seems like order does matter.

Comment: "it's really exactly the same thing as the more familiar class . method technique" - Actually there is one difference: you can't call private methods using "class.method".

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord::Base defined the class method has_many. Ruby lets you call superclass class methods during the definition of a subclass.

You can do this yourself, add your own class methods to ActiveRecord::Base or your own class by making a Module you mix in.

A simple example of how to do this yourself:

```
module MyMixin
  def self.included(base)
    base.extend ClassMethods   # Load class methods
    super
  end
  module ClassMethods
    def hello
      puts "MyMixin says => Hello World"
    end
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, MyMixin
```

Example use:

```
class MyRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  hello
end
```

firing up Rails you would see this printed to the console:

```
MyMixin says => Hello World
```

Comment: This is a good answer but I wonder about *"Ruby lets you call superclass class methods during the definition of a subclass".*  I don't think that's entirely true. The receiver is the class you are defining. You are calling class methods of your own class, and those include methods inherited from the superclass.

Comment: perhaps the wording is over simplified. Didn't really want to get sucked into a long discussion of the meaning of 'self'